# function parameter scope in suspend functions

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

So basically what is the function parameter scope in a suspend function, and is it ok to use activity in a suspend function that could in theory be suspended for a long time

For example:

```
suspend fun function(activity: Activity) = suspendCancellableCoroutine<SomeResult> { continuation ->
    Api.expecuteSomeRequest().onFinishListener { result ->
        //using activity here would be bad
        continuation.resume(result)
    }//for example this request could take a long time, activity could be destroyed by that point
    activity.doSomething() 
    //is using activity here ok, will activity parameter go out of scope after this is executed,
    //or will it wait for the whole suspend function to finish
}
```

real worl usage example:

```
suspend fun Activity.loginWithFacebook() = suspendCancellableCoroutine<AuthCredential> { continuation ->
    val callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create()
    LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, object :
        FacebookCallback<LoginResult> {
        override fun onCancel() {
            continuation.resumeWith(Result.failure(...))
        }

        override fun onError(error: FacebookException) {
            continuation.resumeWith(Result.failure(error))
        }

        override fun onSuccess(result: LoginResult) {
            continuation.resumeWith(Result.success(FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(result.accessToken.token)))
        }

    })
    LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, callbackManager, listOf("public_profile"))
}
```

Comment: As a side note: if you meant to use `Activity` after some time, then note that both `activity.doSomething()` and `logInWithReadPermissions()` are actually invoked immediately, not after resuming.

Answer (score 1):

It would only be okay if these suspend functions were called from a CoroutineScope that is cancelled when the Activity is destroyed, such as `lifecycleScope`. It would not be appropriate for a coroutine called from `viewModelScope`.

For something like your first example, I would remove the activity from the function entirely. Whatever you want to do with your Activity you can do in the activity’s own coroutine.

In the second example, your parameter probably only needs to be a Context. Typically when you pass a Context to an API, you should not pass an Activity, whether or not you’re using a coroutine. You can call `applicationContext` in your Activity to get a Context that you don’t have to worry about leaking.

However both of these functions that interact with UIs would likely benefit from being moved to a ViewModel and publishing to a Deferred or Flow property in the ViewModel. Then if someone opens an Activity that starts a login flow and then rotates the screen while it’s still working, they can still get the result in the new Activity without it having to start over.

Comment: First is just an example, there would be cases where you need activity (like the second example). And in the second example, it has to be an activity, because LoginManager is using ActivityResultRegistryOwner

Comment: So basically, i would somehow have to call `LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this....)` outside of the coroutine?

Comment: I haven't used Facebook in several years. Just browsing the documentation now, and it does indeed seem they do not give you the option to do this without an Activity or Fragment instance. Therefore, I think your second suspend function example is fine, so long as you call it from a coroutine that's running in the `lifecycleScope` of the Activity that's being used to call the extension. I consider this to be a design flaw in the Facebook SDK, that you can't do this in a ViewModel without a Activity/Fragment reference. Their SDK has come a long way, but maybe still has a ways to go to place nice

Comment: with clean design. Back when I used it about 9 years ago, the way you logged in with the SDK was to put their own subclass of Button in your app! The login functionality was built into a Button subclass of their own. This was shockingly bad mingling of concerns and very needlessly limiting. So at least it's better than it used to be! Side note relevant to your question, I just did a test using WeakReference and found that a suspend function does not hold onto parameter references past their last usage inside the suspend function. So if the last line that uses the parameter is followed by a

Comment: suspend function, when that suspend call is reached, the object is free to be released to the GC.